# Stopping an app from hijacking browser downloads

Tags: chrome-for-android, default-applications

I have an app ([EBookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid&hl=en)) that automatically opens all PDF links instead of letting me download them. Is there any way to stop this without uninstalling the app?

I'm on unrooted Android 4.2 and using Chrome as my browser.

Note that EBookDroid has *no* defaults set. If I open a PDF with a file manager then I'm given the option to choose an app to open it with.

Answer (score 9):

Since [EbookDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ebookdroid&hl=en) is [open source](http://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/), I took a quick glance at the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/source/browse/trunk/AndroidManifest.xml), the pertinent information is this part, between lines 24 and 33:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:scheme="smb" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:scheme="https" />
.... SNIP ....
```

The keyword(s) is in the Intent Filter's category

- `android.intent.category.BROWSABLE`
- and the `android:scheme="http"`

With both of these, the app "*listens*" on the http/https *both web, plain and secure* and among others such as `smb` for samba file shares, etc, for the content links that contains the `pdf`, `djvu` and others, identified by the lines between 35 and 43:

```
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.djvu" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.djv" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.xps" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.oxps" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbz" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.cbr" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fb2" />
<data android:pathPattern=".*\\.fb2\\.zip" />
```

This will explain why the app hijacks any browser downloads and thusly

> that automatically opens all PDF links instead of letting me download
>   them

*Why not post an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/ebookdroid/issues/list) on the same site to let the developer know about this*?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but found out that disabling `handle http` in the ebookdroid settings fixes the issue.